# How to combine two conditions to make a plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Is it possible to plot a dataframe using two conditions ?

I have this dataframe :

```
tdat=structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("AS", 
"Dup", "MCH")), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("bot", 
"top", "all"), class = "factor"), value = c(1.009936818, 1.414634463, 
0.778023226, 1.046037598, 2.370167409, 0.714638976, 0.241778577, 
0.684398769, 0.181664019, 0.44099306, 1.212003504, 0.237309508, 
1.257632594, 2.329136359, 1.037219886, 1.495702786, 2.990687546, 
1.069762508)), .Names = c("X", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")

> tdat
     X variable     value
1   AS      bot 1.0099368
2  MCH      bot 1.4146345
3  Dup      bot 0.7780232
4   AS      bot 1.0460376
5  MCH      bot 2.3701674
6  Dup      bot 0.7146390
7   AS      top 0.2417786
8  MCH      top 0.6843988
9  Dup      top 0.1816640
10  AS      top 0.4409931
11 MCH      top 1.2120035
12 Dup      top 0.2373095
13  AS      all 1.2576326
14 MCH      all 2.3291364
15 Dup      all 1.0372199
16  AS      all 1.4957028
17 MCH      all 2.9906875
18 Dup      all 1.0697625
```

I could use

```
 qplot(x=variable, y=value,data=tdat).
```

However I need to make subgroups using both "X" and "variable". So i need 9groups : AS-bot, MCH-bot, Dup-bot, AS-top, etc. So is there a way to tell qplot to use y as y=value+X ?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want to plot against what.. Maybe this'll point the right direction?? not sure though: `ggplot(tdat, aes(x=interaction(X,variable), y=value)) + geom_line()`?

Comment: @Arun brillant! maybe you can add `sep='-'` and put it as an answer !

Comment: @agstudy, yes I will. But maybe after the OP explains whether this is what he's looking for.. :) I don't want to write an answer and go through the edits.. Got a paper to read for tomorrow :P..

Comment: that's exactly what i needed with geom_point(), thank's

Comment: Is ggplot programmed to work with interaction() function ? There is no AS.bot level nor any other combined level in the dataframe and it still works that's strange.

Comment: @Wicelo `ggplot2` captures what do you want to do using `aes` and then  evaluate it later in the right environment( mainly your data will be used as the new environment). It is analogous to the behavior of `with`: `with(tdat, interaction(X,variable,drop=TRUE,sep='-'))`

Comment: @agstudy oh okay I understand, so there is no way to colour the points or the lines using the X levels ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mention in the comment, you can use `interaction`. here I use it twice for 2 aes. To get better legend sub title, I use `scale_color_discrete`.

```
ggplot(tdat, aes(x=interaction(X,variable,drop=TRUE,sep='-'), y=value,
                 color=X)) + 
                 geom_point() +
                 scale_color_discrete(name='interaction levels')
```

[image]

Comment: ok thank's for your answer but for the coloration I would like all the AS to have the same colour, Dup too and MCH too. Since we're using interaction() function I'm not sure it is possible.